# How to open VS 2008 solution in VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions

I have seen [Solutions created in Visual Studio 2008 cannot be opened in Visual Studio 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/djpark/archive/2007/11/07/how-to-use-solutions-and-projects-between-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx) and tried workaround 1. Yet to try the workaround 2.

But as that link was bit old and out of desperation asking here: Is there any convertor available?

---

I dont have VS2008 yet and i wanted to open an opensource solution which was done in vs2008.

Guess i have to fiddle around or wait till the vs2008 is shipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a project that I work on in both VS 2005 and VS 2008.  The trick is just to have to different solution files, and to make sure they stay in sync.  Remember that **projects** keep track of their **files**, so the main thing **solutions** do is keep track of which **projects** they contain; pretty easy to keep in sync.

So just create a new blank solution in VS 2005, and then add each of your projects to it, one by one.  Be sure to name the solutions appropriately.  (I call mine ProjectName.sln and ProjectNameVs2008.sln.)

Which is a long way of saying you should try workaround #2.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [visual studio 2008 to 2005 downgrade tool](http://mises.org/Community/blogs/misestech/archive/2008/02/28/visual-studio-2008-to-2005-downgrade-utility.aspx)
And [another one](http://home.hot.rr.com/graye/Articles/ProjectConverter.htm).

I haven't tried either of these, so please report back if they are successful for you ;-)

Comment: Both use the workaround 1 that i linked in my question. So i didnt have any luck with them :(

Answer (score 2):

You can download and use Visual Studio 2008 Express editions.  They're free...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should restore your 2005 version from source control, assuming you have source control and a 2005 copy of the file.

Otherwise, there are plenty of pages on the net that details the changes, but unfortunately no ready-made converter program that will do it for you.

Be aware that as soon as you open the file in 2008 again, it'll be upgraded once more.

Perhaps the solution (no pun intended) is to keep separate copy of the project and solution files for 2005 and 2008?

Why do you want to open it in 2005 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the problem of opening a VS 2008 web service project in VS2005.

Steps to follow
 - creates a new web service project in vs 2005.
 - Compile the project.
 - OPen the Project file in notepad.
 - Copy the bold font lines
**
 - 
   
       Debug
       AnyCPU
       8.0.50727
       2.0
       {3C596F22-0A57-4B9A-ABD3-C2BEFA5DA0B7}
       {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
       Library
       Properties
       WebService1
       WebService1
      
       true
       full
       false
       bin\
       DEBUG;TRACE
       prompt
       4      
       pdbonly
       true
       bin\
       TRACE
       prompt
       4

**
  
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  
  
    
    
  
  
    
      Service1.asmx
      Component
    
    
  
  **
 -

**
  
  </Target>
  
  </Target>
  -->
  
    
      
        
          False
          True
          3124
          /
          
          
          False

5. Paste them over the webservice file created in the vs 2008. Do not replace the whole file your ref will go replace only where version is given.

My problem is resolved following these i am sure your's will also be resolved